# Add css minHeight to multiple select in react material ui

Tags: drop-down-menu, material-ui, react-bootstrap

I have created a material ui select multiple list and have some values in it. I want to increase the min height of the select, but after applying the minHeight css in the select tag, it does not increase the height of the select box.
This is the CodeSandBox for it. I have commented the place where i tried applying the css minHeight property.

If i inspect element in my browser and apply minHeight:'14rem' to the `class="MuiSelect-root MuiSelect-select MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input"`. It increases the size of the select box perfectly but not able to find its corresponding tag in actual code as in the browser inspect, it have more classes applied from the material ui library.

Here is my codeSandbox demo with comments
https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-breeze-4mshf?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  ...
  formControl: {
    "& option": {
      minHeight: 40
    }
  }
}));

export default function App() {
  ...

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Row>
        {/* LEFT LIST 1 JSX */}
        <Col lg="5">
          <Grid container className={classes.root}>
            <Grid item>
              <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
                <span id="LIST_1">LEFT List 1</span>
                <Select
                  multiple
                  native
                  // it increases the size but do not increase the space between the content resulting in bigger box but extra space at top and bottom
                  // style={{minHeight:'14rem'}}
                  value={selectedValue}
                  inputProps={{
                    id: "LIST_1"
                  }}
                >
                  {leftlist1.map((leftlist1, index) => (
                    // if you apply in line 53 in options it increases the space between the option value
                    // style={{minHeight:'14rem'}}
                    <option key={index} value={leftlist1}>
                      {leftlist1} dsfsf
                    </option>
                  ))}
                </Select>
              </FormControl>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. This kind of work but instead of form control can we apply it to the select tag of material ui. The above css makes the select list height bigger but also spreads the content inside.

Comment: @Ani yes, this is an example so you can put your CSS class in ```Select```. Does this answer solve your problem?

Comment: I tried putting the css class in select and used & with option, it makes the select list height more but it also increases the space between the content.

Comment: @Ani When you set minHeight for each ```option``` inside ```Select```, the space between 2 options will be increased, it's truth. So what do you want to do with the option style?

Comment: i want to make the overall Select Box height bigger, and do not want to apply any css to options. It should be as it is.

Comment: I am sorry i mis understood your solution. It is working as expected. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the specific class styles in the Select component by using `withStyle`. For more classes to update you can check [`Select API`](https://material-ui.com/api/select/)

```js
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import MuiSelect from "@material-ui/core/Select";

const Select = withStyles(theme => ({
  select: {
    minHeight: "14rem"
  }
}))(MuiSelect);
```

Working example :

[image: Edit strange-cherry-832ug]

Comment: Thanks, this directly addresses MuiSelect height. This is helpful.